# C# How I sent DateValue to a database and how to get that value again to a date time picker.?

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a Date-Time-Picker in my c# project, I want send it value to my database (column type Varchar(20)) and return that value again to another Date-Time-Picker, and also i want to know how to get date different form two Date-Time-Pickers...

**Please note I'm a beginner Programming**

1. I want to know the code, how to send date value to my data base (column type Varchar).
2. I want to know the code, how to set that value(value that stored in database) to another date-time-picker.
3. I Want to know the code for how to get date different by using two  date-time-pickers.

Comment: This not how we ask questions. You need to research and try a few things. At this stage you might be better to ask your instructor or friends on how to achieve this task, when you have an actual problem then you come and see us

Comment: add some code you tried please

Comment: lol, @micheal you got me at "then you come and see us"... but it's the plain truth.

Comment: It would be better to use a `DATETIME` column to store a `DateTime` than to use `VARCHAR`.